# GhostScript : Missing digital signature when printing

Tags: printing, digital-signature, ghostscript

We had to replace our signature pad by another product because product was discontinued and pens was very hard to find. We buy Topaz GemView Tablet Display

When customer sign on pad, our custom application watch folder for signed PDF and custom application print paper copy for our backyard staff and one for the customer if they want it

Our custom application use GhostScript to send PDF to specific printer.
Everything work fine with the old signature pad and GhostScript 9.16 on Windows 2012
With the Topaz pad, the PDF print, but there are no signature.
I have updated GhostScript to the latest version, 9.53.3, no signature

Here is a link to a sample signed PDF :
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/997a149ab09640d523397248ae6b161020210127144440/e5adad1b76799726522899389fe9415620210127144513/21e3e8

Here is the command line that I use to send PDF to the printer

```
gswin64c.exe -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -dNumCopies=1 -sPAPERSIZE=letter -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="\\spool\\\srv\ColorPaper" "Signed.Pdf"
```

If I remove all parameter, we can see signature on the screen

```
gswin64c.exe "Signed.Pdf"
```

Does GhostScript can print digital signature on paper ?
Thank you

Comment: It's probably the -dPrinted option. https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.53.3/Use.htm#PDF - drop that option, and it will probably print as you expect. (Oh, and the current release is 9.53.3, you should probably upgrade!).

Comment: This seem to be that, by changing parameter "-dPrinted" for "-dPrinted=false", the signature field are printed correctly.

Comment: Cool, thanks for confirming it, and putting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like chrisl say in it's comment, by changing parameter "-dPrinted" for "-dPrinted=false" solve this issue.

The signature field in the PDF are flagged as "not printable".
When using "-dPrinted=false", GhostScript print PDF like it appear on screen